# Customize the Android calendar event notification tone?

Tags: android

Using the code below to create a new event, is there a way to customize the users event notification tone as well?  Or maybe a more accurate question would be, how do I offer the user a new sound to use as their default Calendar event notification tone?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

Edit:
Added answer per request.

Comment: Yep, added it below.  I forgot I could answer my own question, ha!

Comment: Great, thanks!  Remember, if that is indeed the answer that helped you, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't just reference another answer, links should support your answer, not *be* the answer.  If they are, it's a good indicator that the question is a dupe and might lead it to being closed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In this case the question was in refrence to a custom tone via the code provided. Which as I posted is a no, however, I simply made reference to additional content that is relative to adding a custom notification in android.  Technically 2 separate questions entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as tho this is not possible. However you can go through the process of adding a default audio file the old fashioned way, LOL.  I have code here that does just that: [Setting a custom ringtone produces FileNotFound exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314727/setting-a-custom-ringtone-produces-filenotfound-exception)