# Setting a custom ringtone produces FileNotFound exception?

Tags: android

I'm using the code below and receiving the "FileNotFound" exception. Can anyone explain why this is?  I'm using the emulator to test, 2.3.3.

```
private void setRingtone(){
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.custom_ringtone);
    int size = 0;

    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        fIn.read(buffer);
        fIn.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("trace", "IO 1" + e);         
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/ringtone/";
    String filename = "custom_ringtone.mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists){
        new File(path).mkdirs();
        Log.d("trace", "path added" + path);
    }else{
        Log.d("trace", "path not added" + path);            
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.flush();
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("trace", "FileNotFound" + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("trace", "IO 2" + e);
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "Schedule Cheer");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "One2MM");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

    //Insert it into the database
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath());
    getContentResolver().delete(uri, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath() + "\"", null);
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values); 
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(MainActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

}
```

Comment: Can you use the debugger to pinpoint what line causes the exception? Are you sure that all the file paths actually exist on the emulator? Did you set the emulator up so that you can write to the file system?

Comment: All good questions, thanks! I'm looking into the emulator file system settings now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that you need to declare a permision to write to the external SD Card.

Just add this line to your manifest.xml under the `<manifest>` tag:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Yep, that was also missing.  I had to add an actual amount of storage to the SD Card in the AVD manager as well.  Thanks!